# I wanted to append data in a pre formatted Excel sheet using php(for some reason I can't use the third party tools like phpexcel)

Tags: php

I have a pre formatted excel file(excel 2007) with the fixed header and footer, I need to append the data from SQL server. 
I have tried to use code like:

```
header("Content-type:application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition:filename=$filename");
```

in php to create a new file, but it can't do more control with the sheet's layout, and for some reasons we can't use the third party tools, anybody can give me some advice?

code like this：

```
$res = mssql_query($sql, $conn);
$row = mssql_num_rows($res);
if ($row > 0) {
    echo "<table border='1'>";
    echo "table header";
    for ($i = 0; $i < $row; $i++) {
    $row[$i] = mssql_fetch_assoc($res);
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>data here:{$row[$i]['workdate']}</td>";
    }    
}
```

excel sheet like this:
LOGO IMG HERE
                PHYSICIAN BI-WEEKLY TIME SHEET

```
CHS Entity:     userinfo1                               
Department:     userinfo2                               
Name:       userinfo3                               
Pay Period End Date:        2016/10/8                               

        Please accept this time record as attestation and confirmation of my time.  See undersigned
```

table head here:
    Date/Day        Attendance Code Time In Time Out     Hours  Administrative Code On Call SFH (# of hrs)  Good Sam Oncall (# of hrs)  Research    Notes
            Please click on box under code to select options.
data start here：    datarow1
                    datarow2
                    ...
        Total Hours             0.00        0.00    0.00
footer here:
        Employee Signature & Certification:  I reviewed my attendance record……
        Aprover's Name & Signature:

Comment: can you please add some code what you have tried and what you is your expected output.?

Comment: Thank you for reply, I edit my question for some php code, but the excel sheet can't attach, so the layout is in a mess. You can find the header and footer, in the middle is the data.

Comment: Your trying to create an Excel file using HTML, that's not going to work. To create an Excel you should use the PHPExcel library. But since you can't use third party software, is creating a CSV a viable solution?